# App showing wrong splash and icon image after downloading the app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play, google-play-console

I just uploaded my app on google play console, which is now been approved and it is now in the play store.

[image]

When I download my app from the play store, I notice the splash image and the icon is not showing but when I check it in the android emulator it is working well.

[image]

I built the app with expo react native below is my **app.json** code which look correct to my:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My App",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#7022a9"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/images/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myapp.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myapp.app",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#4628a8"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myapp">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="47.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@oseyi/myapp"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your `AndroidManifest.xml` please.

and check this part:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Find the res folder and right click on it
Select New -> Image Asset.
Specify the path to the icon in the Image Path and set additional options as desired
Click Next and Finish.

I think this solution may help you - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140124/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-android-studio

Comment: I have update my code above see `AndroidManifest.xml` thanks

Comment: What kind of pictures you can see near that`s two strings in your manifest - default or your app icons?

Comment: I don't understand are you saying I should remove this`android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` and `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` or rename it, please can you explain better.

Comment: No. In Studio you can see your icons app pictures in manifest at the left side of the code window. Can you see it?

Comment: I opened my code in vs code and on the left side in the asset folder, i cant see `adaptive-icon.png`, `favicon.php`, `icon.png` and `splash.png` images or are you referring to the emulator.

Comment: ok. I`m understand! in Android Studio you can see actual icon pictures at manifest.xml, If you open project.

Do you have project on GitHub? I think we cannot see this problem in VS code)))

Check this case in Android Studio.

Comment: Ooo I will have to open the project Android Studio that is what you met and Yes, I have the project on GitHub

Comment: can you share it? what you see in project \\mipmap\ic_launcher directory?

Comment: Hi @SorokinHutor I will do that but before that, I think have found the directory in vscode see this --> https://ibb.co/9sDHvG7

Comment: what kind of picture did you see? yours or default?

Comment: Default not mine.

Comment: What about the splash screen image

Comment: I just replace the image in the res folder